# C++ template specialisation for abstract base class

Tags: c++, template-specialization, abstract-base-class

I want to write a `Settings` class to load and store settings of various types:

```
template <typename T>
class Setting {
    std::string m_name;
    T m_defaultValue;

    T load() {
        if(backend.contains(m_name))
            return backend.load<T>(m_name);
        return m_defaultValue;
    }

    void save(const T &value) {
        backend.save(m_name, value);
    }
}
```

The `backend` has implementaions for some basic types, but not for my own. So I need template specializations for my types. My idea is to create a `Serializable` class and derive my classes from it:

```
class Serializable {
public:
    virtual std::string serialize() const = 0;
    virtual void deserialize(const std::string &data) = 0;
}
```

Now I need a template specialization for `load` and `save` in the Setting class to use the `serialize` and `deserialize` functions in Serializable:

```
template<>
void Setting<Serializable>::load()
{
    if(backend.contains(m_name)) {
        Serializable s;
        s.deserialize(backend.load<std::string>(m_name);
        return s;
    }
    return m_defaultValue;
}

template<>
void Setting<Serializable>::save(const Serializable &value)
{
    backend.save(m_name, value.serialize());
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because in `Setting<Serializable>::load()` I cannot instantiate `Serializable s`. But even if I leave out `load` for the time being, it does not work because it `cannot declare field ‘Setting<Serializable>::m_defaultValue’ to be of abstract type ‘Serializable’`.

Is there a way to write a different implementation for all subtypes of `Serializable` but still use a template parameter `T`?

Comment: Which version of c++ are you using? With c++17 you could use `if constexpr`. Otherwise the better option is probably partial template specialization. You can't partially specialize just one method though, you need to specialize the entire class.

Comment: @super Thanks, it works with `if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T&, Serializable&>)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a specialized version of Setting that is only available if the type of the setting inherits from Serializable.

By using partial template specialization with `std::enable_if` you can create a separate Settings class that will only be used if the Setting type implements `Serializable`.

e.g.:

```
// Normal Setting class, for the primitive types your backend supports
template <typename T, typename _ = void>
class Setting {
    std::string m_name;
    T m_defaultValue;

public:
    T load() {
        if(backend.contains(m_name))
            return backend.load<T>(m_name);
        return m_defaultValue;
    }

    void save(const T &value) {
        backend.save(m_name, value);
    }
};

// specialized Setting class that will apply to all classes that implement Serializable
template<typename T>
class Setting<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Serializable, T>>> {
    std::string m_name;
    T m_defaultValue;

public:
    T load() {
        if(backend.contains(m_name)) {
            T s;
            s.deserialize(backend.load<std::string>(m_name));
            return s;
        }

        return m_defaultValue;
    }

    void save(const T &value) {
        backend.save(m_name, value.serialize());
    }
};
```

([heres an example godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xW18EEGhE))

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, when the Backend uses overloaded save function and template specialization for the load function: https://godbolt.org/z/rKafY1KM1

Comment: @Mr.Clear sorry, i missed a `public:` and accidentally reversed the order in `std::is_base_of_v<>`, i've edited my answer. [Here's a working version of your godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1v3rh9Ge5)